# Explanation of pipeline containing egrep, tr and expand

Tags: grep, utilities, tr

Can someone explain the following pipeline to me?

I am trying to filter a list of ports in services so that only the unique port names are listed out. What exactly do `expand` and `tr` do, and what does the regular expression used with `egrep` do?

```
expand regexAufgabe | egrep -v '^#|^$' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d / -f2 | sort | uniq
```

Comment: The only regex in the pipeline is `egrep`. FYI, you should use `grep -E` instead of `egrep`. The regex filters out any lines where the first character is `#` or where the line is blank (zero characters). `expand` changes tabs to spaces. `tr -s ' '` condenses multiple spaces to a single space. `man` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

The `expand` utility converts tabs in a file into spaces, i.e., it "expands the tabs into spaces".  The pipeline starts by doing this to the contents of the file called `regexAufgabe`. See `man expand`.

The `egrep` utility is then used with the option `-v` and the regular expression `^#|^$`.  The `-v` option negates the sense of the test, which means that `egrep` will output each line that does *not* match the given regular expression.  The regular expression matches lines that start with a `#` character or that are empty.  This means that the second step in the pipeline removes lines that are empty and that start with `#`.

The `tr` utility is generally used for translating one set of characters to another, but the pipeline uses it to "squeeze" multiple consecutive spaces together into single spaces.  See `man tr`.

`cut` is then used to extract the second space-delimited field in the resulting data set, and then the second `/`-delimited field from that.

The last two stages of the pipeline, `sort | uniq`, could've been written as the single command `sort -u`.  This sorts the data and removes duplicates.

In short, you have a pipeline that replaces tabs with (single) spaces (and compresses multiple spaces into one), removing empty lines and lines that are commented out.  It then picks out the unique second `/`-delimited field from the second space-delimited field from each line.